# Wordpress Force-Login : Unable to whitelist reset password fully

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a site which uses force login. I've managed to get the reset password page whitelistet but it wont work. When pressing the reset password, the form loads and then it redirects me back to the login page. The email does not get sent out which is a bummer. Any ideas?

I feel like I've whitelisted everything that has with reset password to do.. I've also attached a GIF to show what I mean:
https://gyazo.com/556d6aecb9b94db6c72bc3b0ca5523d2

This is what I use to whitelist pages:

```php
function my_forcelogin_bypasss( $bypass, $visited_url ) {

    // Check if url contains string

    // get current page url
    $current_page_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if ( strpos( $current_page_url, 'reset-link-sent' ) !== false ) {
        return $bypass;
    }

    // Allow these absolute URLs
    $allowed = array(
        home_url( '/min-konto/glemt-adgangskode/' ),
        home_url( '/wp-login.php?checkemail=confirm' ),
        home_url( '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https://example.com/min-konto/glemt-adgangskode/?reset-link-sent=true' ),
        home_url( '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmin-konto%2Fglemt-adgangskode%2F%3Freset-link-sent%3Dtrue' ),
    );
    if ( ! $bypass ) {
        $bypass = in_array( $visited_url, $allowed );
    }

    return $bypass;
}
add_filter( 'v_forcelogin_bypass', 'my_forcelogin_bypasss', 10, 2 );
```

the first url in $allowed works fine, it whitelists the reset password page.. But the form, yeah well... I do not think it has time enough to send the email out before the site reloads and redirects me to login.

The force login plugin that I'm using is this one:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-login/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked what URL the lost password form actually submits to? I think that should be `/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword` by default, but your allowed exceptions don't currently cover that.

Comment: In that function, log or dump `$visited_url` somewhere and inspect it.